# How to call two methods in Angular ngOnInit, one after other

Tags: angular, promise

I have two methods in ngOnInit. The other need the data from first. Both are calling rest service observable methods.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.one().then(userId => this.two(userId));
}
```

How to write these methods so that 'then' chaining works, returning a Promise object?

```
one(){
    restService.getUserId().subscribe(       
        resp => {
            userId: number = resp.result;
        }
    )
}

two(userId: number) { 

restService.getData(userId).subscribe(resp => {
        adress: string = resp.result;
    }
    
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with `then`, turn the observables into promises, and make sure to *return* them.

```
one() {
    return restService.getUserId().toPromise().then(resp => resp.result);
}

two(userId: number) {
    return restService.getData(userId).toPromise().then(resp => resp.result);
}
```

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.one().then(userId => this.two(userId))
              .then(userData => { /* do something with the data */ });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Promises, but Angular projects usually uses [RxJS](https://rxjs.dev/) observables and it [operators](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree)

Note: Your sample code doesn't works since `.subscribe` Observable method differs from `Promise.then`. It don't allow changing the response like this.

In order to work using only rxjs, you can use `pipe` and `map` operator:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs'; // put on top of your file

one(): Observable<{userId: number}> { // declaring the return type is a good practice
  return restService.getUserId().pipe(
    // map() operator act like Array.map by
    // transforming some item using a function
    map((response) => ({ 
      userId: response.result
    }))
  )
}

two(userId: number): Observable<{address: string}> { // declaring the return type is a good practice
  return restService.getData(userId).pipe(
    // map() operator act like Array.map by
    // transforming some item using a function
    map((response) => ({ 
      address: response.result
    }))
  )
}
```

So on ng init where you need to chain the methods you can do this:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs'; // put on top of your file

ngOnInit(){
  this.one().pipe(
    switchMap((response: {userId: number}) => {
      return this.two(response.userId);
    }
  ).subscribe((response: {address: string}) => {
    console.log('the address is', address);
  }
}
```

## Explaining:

### The `pipe()` function

The pipe function works by chaining operators in the stream. You can apply as many operators as you need to get the desired result.

### The `map()` operator

The `map()` operator transforms the result of the previous Observable. As parameter to the `map()` operator you pass a function that receive the original value and return the transformed value.

### The `switchMap()` operator

The `switchMap()` operator acts like the `map()` but instead of returning a value, it returns a new Observable using the result of previous Observable as parameter.

## Is bad to use Promises?

No, it's not, and you can solve this problem with less code by using promises. BUT, I really recommend using RxJS because you stick with the pattern used by angular and most developers.

All native angular code return Observables, so you will always need to convert it into Promises if you want use pure Promises.

Also some complex logics are very easy to solve with RxJS, resulting in some clean and easy to read code.

Comment: Than you for your very detailed answer. This goes in SO favorites, but I Will use promise approach, as it is more readable for me in future.

Answer (score 1):

You may try a simple approach as we already know that two() is getting called after one(). Just add one() to ngOnInIt and call two() inside it, that way two() will get called after we get response from subscription inside one().

```
  one(){
    restService.getUserId().subscribe(resp => {
        this.two(resp.result);
    })
  }

  two(userId: number) {
    restService.getData(userId).subscribe(resp => {
      adress: string = resp.result;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.one();
  }
```

Comment: This is also a way, thanks.